# Windows can't create hibernation file, but there's enough disk space?

Tags: windows-8.1, hibernate

Has anyone got an idea what to make of this error, or how to troubleshoot it?

Hibernation file creation error 0x7f is usually related to disk space. But I just expanded the disk by 70 GB or so, so I know there's at least that much contiguous space available on C:. I've also run dskchk "in case".

Despite this, it's still saying it can't create the hiberfil.sys file.

Screenshots of relevant info:

[image]

**Update responding to.comments:** I haven't rebooted. There are other disks, but all have plenty of space. It's a physical machine not a VM.

Comment: Since expanding the disk space, have you, performed a reboot?  Do you have any other disks connected to the server that is low on disk space?  If this is a virtual machine, then hibernation, isn't supported.  Please edit your question, to include, this vital information.

Comment: It's puzzling, but two things are worth trying: (1) reboot, as implied by @Ramhound's comment; (2) try the `powercfg` command in Safe Mode, command-line only.

Comment: Now this is weird. About 4 reboots later, it was suddenly OK with it......? Thanks, Ramhound, AFH.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the size of hibernation file is 75 percent of physical memory size. According to your information, your physical memory size is 64.0 GB, so the size of the hibernation file is about 48.0 GB, maybe the hibernation file is too large to create.

So first we can compress the hibernation file size by command prompt:

1.Open command prompt, run as administrator.

2.Type "powercfg -h -size **nn**", click "enter"( for example, "powercfg -h -size 50" means that the size of hibernation file is 50 percent of physical memory size. By default, the size of hibernation file is 75 percent of physical memory size, we can set "**nn**" to 50 or smaller).

Then we can try to create hibernation file by command.

Comment: Unlikely. I just added 70GB of space to the disk, and it already had 19GB spare. It's got more than enough for a full 64GB, and I don't want a hibernation setup that can't fully hibernate the machine - it's often using 80-85% of ram and might at times use more.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the key to the problem was manually creating empty hiberfil.sys on c:\ by

```
touch c:\hiberfil.sys
```

Then increased it to 75% of memory

```
powercfg -h -size 75%
```

Then enabled it

```
powercfg.exe /hibernate on
```

Then added it to shutdown options selection in control panel -> System and Security -> Power Options -> Change what the power buttons do -> change settings that are currently available.